# Настройка доступа к разделам форума для отдельных пользователей

Tags: drupal, доступ, форум

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли решение по настройке доступа к разделам Drupal-форума на уровне отдельных пользователей ?

То есть, чтобы пользователи такой-то, такой-то и такой-то могли иметь доступ к определенному разделу форума.
Пользователи такой-то и такой-то имели разрешение что-то писать в эти разделы.
И т.д.

Сейчас, как я понимаю, это реализовано на уровне ролей.

Единственное - только модераторов можно назначать для определенного раздела на уровне пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что вам может подойти модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/forum_access. Правда не помню как там на счет доступа отдельных пользователей, но на практике это оказывается довольно проблематичным, т.к. если пользователей больше 100, то это решение будет отнимать много времени у модераторов.

Проверьте, если такого в модуле нет, то можно поступить не очень элегантно, но работать будет: попробовать создать для каждого форума роли типа `forum_name_view`, `forum_name_post`, `forum_name_access_deneid` и этими ролями уже оперировать в `forum_access` и у нужных пользователей ставить необходимые роли.

Или же попробовать писать свой модуль по примеру `forum_access`, но работающий со списком пользователей. Но проверьте, может он уже это умеет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю можно попробовать в действии https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?